# DataTables FixedHeader doesn't scroll with screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using fixed header with bootstrap, but it's not responsive. It's just fixed, and doesn't move right and left with the table. Any ideas why? I want it to be initiated with each column of the table, and not just get fixed by brute force.

When I scroll down I get the fixed header, when I scroll right, the bar stays fixed nonetheless at the same place, it doesn't move with the table, in other words it's `left` style stays the same and doesn't move :(

Example, scroll down and right and you'll see the header stays fixed.
http://live.datatables.net/giqetigu/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably your settings, I played your table settings and this seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      fixedHeader: true,
        responsive: true,
        aLengthMenu: [
            [500, 1000,  -1],
            [500, 1000, "All"]
        ]
    } );
} );
```

I suspect you're missing a few options over at `new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );` which is causing your issue.

Comment: This doesn't work. Are you sure just adding `fixedHeader: true,` for you solved it? It doesn't seem to do anything on my end.

Comment: yes, seems to be working on your link, I've also removed the `new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );` line as well.

Comment: Yes it's working on my link, thanks for that :) but unfortunately in my code it doesn't work. Header still do not move right with the table :/

Comment: ah, well that's interesting. might be worth adding some of your actual code to the question instead.